# how change this mongo query to return zero if match condition don't satisfy in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider I have this mongo query:

```
db.Employee.aggregate(
       [
       { $match: {Date:  { $gte : new ISODate("2018-07-23T00:07:30.767Z") }}},
          {
             $project: {
                info:{$subtract:[{ "$size":{  "$NewBalance"} }, { "$size": {"$OldBalance"}} ] },
         }
      },
   {"$match": {info:{$ne:0}}},
             {"$count":"infoCount"},
             {"$project":{"infoCount":"$infoCount","category":"Employee"}}


   ]
)
```

In every situation this query should project infoCount and category, but now because in some cases that nothing match with {info:{$ne:0}} It does not return any thing, now if this match satisfies I have this:

```
{ 
    "infoCount" : NumberInt(17), 
    "category" : "Employee"
}
```

and I want if nothing match with {info:{$ne:0}} it return this way:

```
   { 
        "infoCount" : NumberInt(0), 
        "category" : "Employee"
    }
```

** NewBalance and OldBalance both are array.

EDIT:
My collection is like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56bb2af2ea13c90c8a0809"),  

    "Date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:37:46.326+0000"), 
    "OldBalance" : [
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:37:45.951+0000"), 
            "Balance" : "500"
        }, 
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:53:00.071+0000"), 
            "Balance" : "200"
        }
    ], 
        "NewBalance" : [
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:37:45.951+0000"), 
            "Balance" : "500"
        }, 
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:53:00.071+0000"), 
            "Balance" : "200"
        },
                {
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:53:00.071+0000"), 
            "Balance" : "200"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case I expect :

```
{ 
    "infoCount" : NumberInt(1), 
    "category" : "Employee"
}
```

if these two arrays length are equavalent I should return:

```
{ 
    "infoCount" : NumberInt(0), 
    "category" : "Employee"
}
```

Comment: Use `$or` inside with `$match` here... and what is `$count` here?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet It counts number of documents that match the condition, and if i use or it returns all documents and no need condition, it is not the thing I want

Comment: If you are using `$count` here then what is the need of `$project` here... `$count` always returns the single field with the count of the documents... In your case it should return something like this `infoCount: 10(number of docs)`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am force to return object a bow with infoCount and category in every case even count is zero.

Comment: Ok post your sample collection and the output you want

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I posted that

Comment: `$count` returns only when the data with matching criteria founds... So you have to  manage this with the javascript code because aggregate cannot do anything here